# What is wrong with this richfaces menu rendering?

Tags: java, css, jsf, richfaces, rendering

I am trying to fix this jsf richfaces menu. Some components does not respect the height that I am giving: 
[image: Pay attention to the red right border]

Here it is my jsf code:

```
    <div style="background:url(#{facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}/images/sigelp_menubar_bg.jpg) repeat-x #4a71a5; text-align:left; height:30px; width:100%; border:0;">
        <h:form style="height:30px">
            <rich:toolbar style="width:auto; background: none; height:30px; vertical-align:middle; padding:0;" itemStyle="border-right: 1px solid red; padding:0; margin:0; height: 30px;"> 
                <rich:toolbarGroup style="padding:0; margin:0;">
                    <rich:dropDownMenu style="padding:0; background:none; height:30px" >
                        <f:facet name="label" style="padding:0; margin:0;">
                            <h:outputText value="Administrar" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <rich:menuGroup label="Estadios" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarEstadios}" iconDisabled="true">
                            <rich:menuItem label="Listar" action="#{menuBean.listarEstadios}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoListarEstadios}"/>
                            <rich:menuItem label="Agregar" action="#{menuBean.agregarEstadio}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAgregarEstadios}"/>
                        </rich:menuGroup>
                        <rich:menuGroup label="Deportes" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarDeportes}">
                            <rich:menuItem label="Listar" action="#{menuBean.listarDeportes}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoListarDeportes}"/>
                            <rich:menuItem label="Agregar" action="#{menuBean.agregarDeporte}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAgregarDeportes}"/>
                        </rich:menuGroup>
                        <rich:menuGroup label="Equipos" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarEquipos}">
                            <rich:menuItem label="Listar" action="#{menuBean.listarEquipos}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoListarEquipos}"/>
                            <rich:menuItem label="Agregar" action="#{menuBean.agregarEquipo}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAgregarEquipos}"/>
                        </rich:menuGroup>
                        <rich:menuGroup label="Torneos" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarTorneos}">
                            <rich:menuItem label="Listar" action="#{menuBean.listarTorneos}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoListarTorneos}"/>
                            <rich:menuItem label="Agregar" action="#{menuBean.agregarTorneo}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAgregarTorneos}"/>
                        </rich:menuGroup>
                        <rich:menuGroup label="Empleados" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarEmpleados}">
                            <rich:menuItem label="Listar" action="#{menuBean.listarEmpleados}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoListarEmpleados}"/>
                            <rich:menuItem label="Agregar" action="#{menuBean.agregarEmpleado}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAgregarEmpleados}"/>
                        </rich:menuGroup>
                        <rich:menuItem label="Categorias" action="#{menuBean.administrarCategorias}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarCategorias}"/>
                        <rich:menuGroup label="Seguridad" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarSeguridad}">
                            <rich:menuItem label="Usuarios" action="#{menuBean.listarUsuarios}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoListarUsuarios}"/>
                            <rich:menuGroup label="Perfiles" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarPerfiles}">
                                <rich:menuItem label="Listar" action="#{menuBean.listarPerfiles}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoListarPerfiles}"/>
                                <rich:menuItem label="Agregar" action="#{menuBean.agregarPerfil}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAgregarPerfiles}"/>   
                            </rich:menuGroup>
                        </rich:menuGroup>
                    </rich:dropDownMenu>
                    <rich:menuItem label="Administrar socios" action="#{menuBean.administrarSocios}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.validarPermisoAdministrarSocios}"/>
                    <rich:dropDownMenu>
                        <f:facet name="label">
                            <h:outputText value="Cuotas sociales" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <rich:menuItem label="Generar cuotas sociales" action="#{menuBean.generarCuotasSociales}"/>
                        <rich:menuItem label="Listar cuotas sociales sin rendir" action="#{menuBean.listarCuotasSocialesSinRendir}"/>
                    </rich:dropDownMenu>
                    <rich:menuItem label="Vender entradas" action="#{menuBean.venderEntradas}"/>
                </rich:toolbarGroup>
                <rich:toolbarGroup location="right">
                    <rich:menuItem label="Salir" action="#{loginBean.logout}" />
                    <ui:insert name="backButton">
                        <a4j:region>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{seguridadBean.volver}" rendered="#{seguridadBean.showBackButton}" immediate="true">
                            <h:graphicImage value="/images/arrows/arrow-left.png" alt="Volver" style="border: 0px;" width="32"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                        </a4j:region>
                    </ui:insert>
                </rich:toolbarGroup>
            </rich:toolbar>
        </h:form>
    </div>
```

And some intentions to fix trough CSS:

> ```
>  .rf-ddm-itm-unsel{   border:0;   }    .rf-ddm-lbl-dec{   height:100%; }
> ```
>
> .rf-ddm-itm:hover {   margin:0;   padding:0;  background: #7BA0D2; }
>
> .rf-tb-itm{   height: 30px; }
>
> .rf-tb {  padding: 0;     margin:0; }
>
> .rf-tb-itm, .rf-ddm-lbl, .rf-ddm-unsel{   line-height: 30px;  padding:
>   0;    margin: 0; }

Any hint or help would be appreciated, thank you very much

The red border is defined inside `<rich:toolbar itemStyle="border-right: 1px solid red; padding:0; margin:0; height: 30px;">`

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of the HTML output?

Comment: I still looking for a solution, mother of god

Comment: Can you provide the url to the background-image you are using as this will be key to solving the problem. On the jsfiddle there is no background image available to work against your problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forget that part, I will be uploading it soon

Comment: Background Image updated! http://jsfiddle.net/QSvZu/4/ ; thank you!